# Make hover over one class affect all other of same class on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I'm looking to make a hover over list items in a sub nav activate a class on all of the items in that category on the page (not just parent or sibling elements).  Any ideas?  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<style>
img.BLUE {border:1px solid #FFF}
</style>

<ul id="subnav">
<li id="BLUE">Blue</li> <!--When hovering these...-->
<li id="PINK">Pink</li>
<li id="YELLOW">Yellow</li>
</ul>

<!--other stuff here-->

<img class="BLUE" href="image.jpg"> <!--it applies the border to this and any other img.blue on the page-->
<img class="PINK" href="image1.jpg">
<img class="YELLOW" href="image2.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do what you want..

```
<style type="text/css">
   img.active{border:1px solid #FFF;}
</style>
```

and

```
$('#subnav li').hover(function(){
  $('.' + this.id).addClass('active');
},function(){
  $('.' + this.id).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm having trouble implementing the script.  I'm likely fuddling it with the class/id pairings.  Can you show the html side?

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/j9zux/2/)

```
$('#subnav li').hover(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');                     // grab ID of clicked el
    $('img.'+id).css({border: '1px solid #fff'});    // image class=IDname : add CSS prop.
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP specifically asks for **hover** not click.